# \ref and \label

Tags: cross-referencing, texmaker

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,draft]{article}‎
‎\usepackage{seamb}‎
\begin{document}‎‎
\begin{lem}\label{t2} 
  This is my lemma.
\end{lem}



By Lemma \ref{t2}, we have 
\end{document}
```

But the output is :

**Lemma 0.1. This is my lemma.**

**By Lemma , we have**

I mean  \ref does not work here.

Ps. The important part is seamb pachackege which includes three files and it is not online.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Please post not just some code snippets, but a minimum working example (MWE for short, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that reproduces the problem you're looking to solve. In particular, since the problem only seems to occur when you're using a certain "template" (a LaTeX document class? a LaTeX package?), please indicate where the template might be found online.

Comment: I suppose an unnumbered Lemma. But without knowing your documentclass it is difficult to say what went wrong.

Comment: @Negin: You're right that `seamb` is important... but where can we find it?

Comment: This is a template which the journal sent to me and it is online. Maybe it is better I ask the editor of journal first.

Comment: since the necessary `seamb.sty` file is not online, there is nothing we can do to check it.  however, this looks to me like a serious deficiency in its theorem/proof support.  do ask the editor of the journal why the `\ref` mechanism isn't working, and suggest that it be made to work like other uses of `\ref` when `article` is used with *no* other packages loaded.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the errors that are describe would seem to be the result of the OP using a proprietary package, viz., "seamb".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that cannot be reproduced without the necessary style file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You easily define any theorem-like enunciation on your own with amsthm-package.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,draft]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newcounter{lem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[lem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\label{t2} 
This is my lemma.
\end{lemma}

By Lemma \ref{t2}, we have 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I should use seamb package as well and they do not work toghether.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @ SLx64: yes, when I click on the error massege it goes to the following line in "seamb" package:                                                        \newenvironment{proof}{\vspace{-2mm}\begin{sloppypar}\noindent{\it Proof.\enspace}\ignorespaces}{\hspace*{\fill}\rule{1.7mm}{1.7mm}\end{sloppypar}\dl}‎

Comment: But without my example everything works fine?

Comment: Yes. But  \ref does not work.

Comment: Does any other ref-package work? Try to add \usepackage{cleveref} and use \cref{t2}.

Comment: @Negin: Where can we download the `seamb.sty`?

Comment: @SLx64: If we have \theoremstyle{plain}‎, then we will have two more errors. But I remove it now my outline is By Lemma ??, we have.

Comment: @Herbert: Sorry, but this template is not online.

Answer (score 0):

When you call label, what happens is that it writes a record to auxout which is read the next time latex is run.  To debug, examine the contents of auxout, or expand \@currentlabel and \@currentlabelname in your code (you will need to use \makeatletter ... \makeatother around your macro definition).  Or you could just set \@currentlabel to be what you want displayed by \ref before expanding \label.

```
\def\label#1{% one of many definitions
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \def\label@name{#1}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{#1}{%
        {\@currentlabel}% set by \refstepcounter
        {\thepage}%
        {\@currentlabelname}% depends on type of label
        {\@currentHref}{}% used by hyperref
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}%

\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \def\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}}%
```